# SQL Server 2008 trying to cast varchar as a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, sum, decimal

I have results from three columns

```
GameDate    SALES   PRIZES
2013-10-22  2720931 2464831
2013-10-23  3263324 3212128
2013-10-24  2662691 2484328
2013-10-25  4530379 4487401
2013-10-26  1902184 1835012
2013-10-27  2145961 1948877
2013-10-28  1059279 935004
2013-10-29  2493122 2244758
2013-10-30  3309022 2987442
```

I used this to get it

```
select 
    cast(CurrentDate - 7.0/24 as date) as GameDate,
    SUM(TotalBet) as SALES, SUM(TotalWin) as PRIZES
from 
    play WITH (nolock) 
where 
    CurrentDate > '10/1/2013 00:00:00' and CurrentDate < '10/31/2013 00:00:00'
group by 
    cast(CurrentDate - 7.0/24 as date)
order by 
     1;
```

I want to make the results have two decimal places and cannot figure out he cast or convert statement to do it.

Comment: Presume you've tried `CAST(SUM(TotalBet) AS DECIMAL) as SALES`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the string up and shove a decimal in there.  I'm assuming that you want the last 2 characters as the decimals?

I took your data and made something up to demonstrate:

```
sum (cast (left (TotalBet,len(TotalBet)-2) + '.' + right(totalbet,2) as decimal(10,2)))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55b35/7)